# $ \int \frac{x^2-x}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

My problem, is how to find the integral of $$ \int \frac{x^2-x}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

And I don't even know where to start. I tried factoring out x, but I don't get anything useful. I need some suggestions please.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Factor the top, using difference of perfect squares.

Comment: To integrate an integral, you first need to find the primitive of the integrand, and once found find a primitive of the resulting function. This is probably not what you meant. Moral: you should either say "find the integral" or "integrate the expression", but not what you said in the title and wrote in the question.

Comment: $x^2-x=(x-\sqrt x)(x+\sqrt x)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that $x^2-x=(x+\sqrt{x})(x-\sqrt{x})$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \int \frac{x^2-x}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x= \int \frac{(x-1)\sqrt {x}}{1+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x=\int \left(\sqrt {x}-1\right)\sqrt {x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\sqrt x$ then $dx=2tdt$ hence
$$ \int \frac{x^2-x}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x=2\int\frac{t^4-t^2}{t+1}\, \mathrm{d}t=2\int t^2(t-1)\, \mathrm{d}t$$
which we can integrate easily.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition for a denominator of degree$~1$, seriously?

Comment: Well in this case no, but in general why not? how you integrate $\int \frac{t^2}{t+1}dt$?

Comment: There was no  any partial fraction decomposition, usual division

Comment: @Leox This usual division is a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane, No. After this division we have got  a polynomial, not  a fraction.

Comment: @Leox Look I know that in the given case it's useless to talk about the pfd and that's why I edited my answer but as I said even for a denominator of degree $1$  it's a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane, OK

Answer (score 2):

We have $$ \int \frac{x^2-x}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, dx=\int (x-\sqrt{x} ) dx. $$

It is sum of table integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Factor the top using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$:
$$ \int \frac{(x+\sqrt{x})(x-\sqrt{x})}{x+\sqrt {x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
Simplifying we obtain:
$$ \int x-\sqrt{x}, \mathrm{d}x$$
Which can be easily integrated to:
$$ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't see that the fraction simplifies, you can *always* integrate a rational expression involving only a single simple square root by changing variable to that square root. Here putting $u=\sqrt x$ gives $x=u^2$ so $\def\d{\,\mathrm d}\!\d x=2u\d u$, and you get
$$
  \int \frac{(x^2-x)\d x}{x+\sqrt {x}}=\int\frac{(u^4-u^2)2u\d u}{u^2+u}.
$$
Now you are *forced* to do the polynomial division and find that $2u(u^4-u^2)=2(u^2+u)(u^3-u^2)$, so you are looking at
$$
  \int2(u^3-u^2)\d u=\frac14u^4-\frac23u^3+C=\frac14x^2-\frac23x\sqrt x+C.
$$